# how to pass model data to next activity

Tags: android

i am trying to pass model to next activity by using putexra i am geeting error

```
Dtr_Transfermation_vo dtr_transfermation_vo=new Dtr_Transfermation_vo();
dtr_transfermation_vo.setFEEDER(stringFeeds);
dtr_transfermation_vo.setSTRUCTER_CODE(stringStructerCode);
dtr_transfermation_vo.setSSNO(stringSSNO);
dtr_transfermation_vo.setLANMARK(stringLandMark);
dtr_transfermation_vo.setLOADTYPE(stringLoadType);
dtr_transfermation_vo.setPHASE(stringPhase);
dtr_transfermation_vo.setCAPACITY_KVA(stringCapacity);
dtr_transfermation_vo.setMANIFACTURE_DATE(stringPtrDate);

i.putExtra("data",dtr_transfermation_vo);
startActivity(i);
```

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: Are u passing Object??

Comment: dtr_transfermation_vo You pass right?? Its is Object Of your Model?

Comment: The method putExtra(String, boolean) in the type Intent is not applicable for the arguments (String, Dtr_Transfermation_vo)

Comment: I am getting above error

Answer (score 0):

If you have to pass modal to Intent use -

Declare your model with implementation of Serializable

import java.io.Serializable;

public class YourModel implements Serializable {

```
String ID;   
String Name;     


public String getID() {
    return ID;
}

public void setID(String id) {
    ID = id;
}  

public String getName() {
    return ID;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    Name = name;
}
```

}

Then while start intent

```
YourModel model = new YourModel();

model.setID("001");
model.setName("John Smith");

Intent i = new Intent(this, NextClass.class);
Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(), JobCardActivity.class);
i.putExtra("object", model);
```

For Bundle -

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putSerializable("object", model);
i.putExtra("object", bundle);
```

Answer (score -1):

You should consider read about Intents in Android, with Intents you can communicate between Android objects such as activities, services, fragments etc and pass data to them.

Check [this article](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html) of the documentation to see the right way to pass data between activities in Android.